# Chart.js custom charts

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

[Example graph depicting the desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRpwi.png)

I'm trying to create a chart with Chart.js which resembles the chart above...also if any other charting library makes this easier then please shout!

The chart needs to have:

- Coloured areas which highlight morning, afternoon & evening with custom a background image for the icon.
- A line graph which depics the number of calls made during each hour
- A legend of numbers at the bottom

I'm at a slight loss on how to do this natively by extending Chart.js so any help would be appreciated for custom chart examples or an idea of how to execute this.

```
var rangesStart = scale.calculateX(0);
var rangesEnd = scale.calculateX(23);
var gradient = this.chart.ctx.createLinearGradient(0, rangesStart, 0, rangesEnd);

ranges.forEach(function (range) {
  gradient.addColorStop((scale.calculateX(range.start) - rangesStart) / (rangesEnd - rangesStart), range.color);
  gradient.addColorStop((scale.calculateX(range.end) - rangesStart) / (rangesEnd - rangesStart), range.color);
})
```

I did attempt this here, but couldn't get the desired result, the colours seem to go horizontially instead of vertically.

http://jsfiddle.net/shxnhdfd/

Answer (score 3):

Solved issues by using the beginPath() method

```
ctx.beginPath();

        ranges.forEach(function (range) {

          var numbersBetween = range.end - range.start

          ctx.fillStyle = range.color;
          ctx.fillRect(_this.datasets[0].points[range.start].x - 0 * unitX, yTop, unitX * numbersBetween, yHeight);
        })

        ctx.fill();
```

Working fiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/cvwporru/2/